# What does "preceding" mean in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Could anyone please explain to me how the following code executes and what is the meaning of `preceding` keyword in Oracle?

```
SUM(WIN_30_DUR) OVER(PARTITION BY AGENT_MASTER_ID 
                      ORDER BY ROW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
```

Hey Thanks for your clarification. I have a small doubt.

Let say if we have 59 days of data from 1st jan to 28 feb. What data this function gets?

Comment: If in doubt, read the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i97640

Comment: You'll better understand from this link , or try to from: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce6b4/3/0 , and for someone too

Answer (score 3):

You obviously are querying a table `T` with columns `WIN_30_DUR`, `AGENT_MASTER_ID` and `ROW_DT` (among others). Keep in mind that keywords like `OVER`, `PARTITION` show you're using an analytical request: such requests allow you to get information on the current row from the other ones, that would be complex and long to write with `GROUP BY` or other "standard" clauses.

Here, on a given row, you:

- group (`PARTITION`) by `AGENT_MASTER_ID`: this gets all the rows of `T` with current `AGENT_MASTER_ID`
- in the partition formed you `ORDER` rows by `ROW_DT`
- this ordering allows you to select the 30 rows before the current `ROW_DT`: this is the meaning of the `PRECEDING` keyword (`0` would select the current row, the opposite is the `FOLLOWING` clause)
- then you do a sum on the `WIN_30_DUR` field

In usual language, this would mean something like: for each agent, take the sum of durations of the preceding 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

```
select row_dt, win_30_dur,
agent_master_id,
SUM(WIN_30_DUR) OVER(PARTITION BY AGENT_MASTER_ID 
                      ORDER BY ROW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) running_sum
from test;
```

It uses `ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND 0 PRECEDING` for returning the results upto the current row. , that is partitioned by the column `AGENT_MASTER_ID` in your table which is ordered by the `ROW_DT`.

So, in your query it returns the sum of values of `AGENT_MASTER_ID` that is preceding between 30 and 1 rows above the current row.

for better understanding: see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce6b4/4/0

Comment: Hey Thanks for your clarification...i have a small doubt.

Let say if we have 59 days of data from 1st jan to 28 feb. What data this function gets?

Pl explain.

Thanks...!

Comment: You'll get the result, ie; sum of the values from 27th feb to 30 rows above, and partitioned by the AGENT_MASTER_ID.

Comment: That means we will not get FEB 28th day data ..right? i.e IF i declare ROWS BETWEEN 30 preceding and 1 preceding then i will get last 29 days of data excluding current day of data.. Pl explain

Comment: if you need it, you need to include `ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 0 PRECEDING`

Comment: hmmm...can you pl explain me what is 30 preceding? and what is 1 preceding? Thanks for help...

Answer (score 0):

ROWS BETWEEN is the windowing clasue. It is used to specify what rows are considered while evaluating the analytic function.

Breaking down the clauses,

- PARTITION BY AGENT_MASTER_ID  : The rows are partitioned by agent_master_id. That means, while evaluating the function for a particular row, only those rows are considered which which have agent_master_id same as that of the current row.
- ORDER BY ROW_DT : The column by which the rows are ordered within each partition.
- ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING : This specifies within each partition, consider only those rows starting from the row which precedes the current row by 30, till the row which precedes the current row by 1. Essentially, 30 previous rows.

For explanation purpose lets assume this is how your table looks like. Under the `sum_as_analytical` I have mentioned what rows are included while calculating the SUM.

```
agent_master_id win_30_dur  row_dt      sum_as_analytical
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1               12          01-01-2013  no preceding rows. Sum is null
1               10          02-01-2013  only 1 preceding row. sum = 12
1               14          03-01-2013  only 2 preceding rows. sum = 12 + 10
1               10          04-01-2013  3 preceding rows. sum = 12 + 10 + 14
.               .
.               .
.               .
1               10          30-01-2013  29 preceding rows. sum = 12 + 10 + 14 .... until value for 29-01-2013
1               10          31-01-2013  30 preceding rows. sum = 12 + 10 + 14 .... until value for 30-01-2013
1               20          01-02-2013  30 preceding rows. sum = 10 + 14 + 10 .... until value for 31-01-2013
.               .
.               .
.               .
1               10          28-02-2013  30 preceding rows. sum = sum of values from 29th Jan to 27th FeB
2               10          01-01-2013  no preceding rows. Sum is null
2               15          02-01-2013  only 1 preceding row. sum = 10
2               14          03-01-2013  only 2 preceding rows. sum = 10 + 15
2               12          04-01-2013  3 preceding rows. sum = 10 + 15 + 14
.               .
.               .
.               .
2               23          31-01-2013  30 preceding rows. sum = 10 + 15 + 14 .... until value for 30-01-2013
2               12          01-02-2013  30 preceding rows. sum = 15 + 14 + 12 .... until value for 31-01-2013
.               .
.               .
.               .
2               25          28-02-2013  30 preceding rows. sum = sum of values from 29th Jan to 27th FeB
```

Few other examples of windowing clasue,

- UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING : All preceding rows, current row, all following rows.
- 2 PRECEDING and 5 FOLLOWING : 2 preceding rows, current row and 5 following rows.
- 5 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW : 5 preceding rows and current row.
- CURRENT ROW and 1 FOLLOWING : Current row, 1 following row.
- Windowing clause is optional. If you omit it, the default in Oracle is UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW, which essentially gives the cumulative total.

  Here's a simple [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a03f/1).

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by assigning result into list..

List<> BOS = Orders1.ToList<>();

```
            decimal running_total = 0;
            var result_set =
                from x in BOS
                select new
                {
                    DESKTOPS = x.NOTEBOOKS,
                    running_total = (running_total = (decimal)(running_total + x.NOTEBOOKS))
                };`enter code here`
```